# ffmpeg encoded video has video/audio sync delay when uploading to Facebook & WhatsApp

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

```
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    node : 8
```

#### Code to reproduce

```js
let command = ffmpeg()
        .input(tempFilePath)
        .input(watermarkFilePath)
        .complexFilter([
            "[0:v][1:v]overlay=W-w-20:H-h-20"
        ])
        .videoBitrate(2500)
        .videoCodec('libx264')
        .audioCodec('aac')
        .format('mp4')
        .output(targetTempFilePath)
```

When applying the ffmpeg encoding command on the attached video, it plays fine on a local device - the issue however is when uploading to Facebook/WhatsApp **the audio/video becomes out of sync**

Any ideas on what i need to change in terms of the video/audio settings so that the audio + video are in sync, even when uploaded to the various social networks?

Here's a link to the 3 video files (original, post ffmpeg, post whatsapp upload that includes delay) if you want to get a better idea!

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/445dfaf0f323a73c56201b818dc0267b20191213052112/24e635

Thank you and appreciate any help!!